# Algebra-module over a set, is there such a thing?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, algebras, hecke-algebras

I'm reading a paper and $H$ is an algebra and $M$ is a set. And then they define $M|H$ to be the "$H$-module $M$". Is it obvious what this is or is it bad math description? My guess is the free $H$-module generated by the set $M$.

Comment: Is the paper available online?

Comment: I would also guess the same. What else could it be?

Comment: @rschwieb: no, the paper is not yet online. I am reviewing it for a local journal.

Comment: It's unclear. Is there any way they didn't actually merely intend to talk about a real $H$-module $M$? $M$ is something that you call modules, not the generator set of a free module...  Will you eventually be giving feedback to the person directly? You can also report to your superiors that it is not entirely clear what (item 1, item2, item3) meant as written, and clarification would be nice.

Comment: Come to think of it, $H$ is a fairly weird name for an algebra in the first place.

Comment: @rschwieb: Thanks I gave indirect feedback that it should be elaborated. $H$ is not a strange letter for a Hecke algebra :)